# Mysql very special Like requirement

Tags: mysql, sql-like

My case is as below.

I have below records in a mysql table in a "productname" column.

```
Adults-Work-Blue-Green-Pink-Ghagra-Choli-Dupatta
Afro-Party-Retro-Wigs-Hair-Black-Curly-Gabbar
```

Now I want to find record which starts with A and then after first hyphen W.

If I write query as below,

```
select DISTINCT Item_Code, Item_Name
from tbl_stock_detail
where Item_Name like 'A%-W%'
```

It shows me both records. I want to see only first record here as after A, W is the first letter after Hyphen. Similarly If I make it like 'A%-W%-B%', I want it to show only first record as after 'A', 'W' is the first letter after first hyphen and 'B' is the first letter after second hyphen. Just remember, there are 1000s of records with variety of names, so we cant check the string length.

Can I write such query in mysql which check the sequence as well?

Sorry I am bad at Regex . This might be possible with regex.

Please advise.

Edited Question below :

I have a record like this "Long Skirt red sequin tikli dance"
Now client says, he want to search based on these 3 characters only,
R : Red
T : Tikli
S : Skirt

Also second thing plz.
If Skirt and Red has 2 spaces instead of 1, our old regex doesnt work. But it should work as they have mistakenly added multiple spaces between 2 words sometimes.
can you plz help me to fulfill these 2 requirements?

More Editing :

This works static but it gives me some escape sequence problem in PHP. Below is my php code,

```
<?php
$var = 'SRT';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($var);$i++)  
{
    $term = '^'.$var[$i].'|[- ]'.$var[$i];  
    if($i == 0)
        $subquery0 .= " where Item_Name REGEXP '".$term."'";    
    else
        $subquery0 .= " or Item_Name REGEXP '".$term."'";   
}
?>
```

When I echo $term, it shows '^S only.
But If I remove | symbol then it shows complete string .
May be pipe symbol needs escape sequence I tried it as '//|' but it doesnt work.
Any idea on this or I have to open a new question as this is a PHP question?

Comment: `Item_Name REGEXP 'A[^-]+-W.*'` should work.

Comment: @hjptter92: I think there needs to be a leading caret in the regular expression e.g. **`'^A'`** to match the beginning of the string, per the spec "record starts with A", the rest of the regular expression looks perfect.

Comment: Thanks hjptter92 for helping me.

Comment: The code to assign the value to the `$term` variable looks right, I can't explain why `echo "$term";` would only "show" the first two characters. If this is returned as HTML or XML, maybe(?) the browser it's being viewed in is evaluating the pipe and/or square brackets. Maybe take a look at the page source? (To get more of a clue of what's going on, you could echo length of the string **`echo strlen($term)`**. Or convert the string to hex, and echo the hex representation. (On a SQL note, I think you want to combine those predicates with "AND" rather than "OR".)

Comment: I'd recommend you whittle the "only showing first two characters" down to very simple PHP example, e.g. `$term = '^S|[- ]S'; echo $term;` test that, and if there's a problem, ask another question. (I tested part of your code in PHP Sandbox, saved at: [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5710e37687d80f42c36d671ebb34993ede0ede1f](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5710e37687d80f42c36d671ebb34993ede0ede1f) and output was what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hjpotter92 suggests in his comment, you should be able to use a regular expression to locate the rows with the specified matches.

A single `LIKE` predicate can't perform this type of matching. (It would take knowledge of the maximum length of each component ('Adults','Work', et al.) and a whole unwieldy boatload of LIKE predicates and'ed and or'd together for all the various possible lengths. We we do not want to go there.)

Regular expressions are nothing to be afraid of. Regular expressions can become fairly involved, but that's where they reveal their power and become very useful.

---

To match first character is an 'A' (either capital or lowercase), later followed by a hyphen, immediately following the first hyphen is a 'W', you could do something like this:

```
 WHERE Item_Name REGEXP '^A[^-]*-W'
```

Similarly, starting with A, followed (some point later) by a hyphen, immediately following the next hyphen a 'W', followed (later) by another hyphen and a 'B'

```
 WHERE Item_Name REGEXP '^A[^-]*-W[^-]*-B'
```

---

Let's unpack that last regular expression a bit, piece by piece:

**`^A`**

The first caret matches the beginning of the string, and the character A matches a character A (note: that's a case insensitive match on connections to my databases). So that says, "starting with A or a".

**`[^-]*`**

this part matches any number of characters which are not a hyphen.

**`-W`**

this part matches a hyphen immediately followed by a W. (Because of the immediately preceding part, this would be the first hyphen that occurs after the A that was previously matched.)

**`[^-]*`**

again, any number of characters (zero or more) which are not a hyphen character

**`-B`**

matches a hyphen immediately followed by a B. Again, this would be the first hyphen following the W that was matched.

And the remainder of the string can be anything.

Comment: I cant be thankful enough to you. You explained so nicely. Thanks a lot.. It worked for me :)

Comment: spencer7593 how can we use this if I want '-' or ' '(space) to be allowed before every first letter. I tried this but didnt work. '^A[^- ]*-W[^- ]*-B'

Comment: @Vivek: that's close, but you'd also need to allow a match with a space -or- a hyphen, preceding the **`W`**. Just replace that hyphen immediately before the **`W`** with **`[- ]`**, that will allow a match to either a hyphen or a space. Do the same thing before the **`B`** Something like this should work: **`^A[^- ]*[- ]W[^- ]*[- ]B`**

Comment: @Vivek: Consider "accepting" an answer to the questions you've asked, to let other StackOverflow users know that this question has been answered. And yYour future questions may get more attention if your previous questions have accepted answers.

Comment: Oh sure. I will do that. but my client has made the requirement more complicated. Can you tell me how to that? I have edited the question for that. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: MySQL uses POSIX regular expression engine, so it doesn't support negative lookaheads. If those letters can occur in any sequence, then I think you'll need to "and" together a series of three REGEXP, one to check for the `T`, one to check for the `R` one to check for the `S`. Each of the matches can be either as the first character in the string, or immediately following a space or hyphen character. Try something like this: **`foo REGEXP '^T|[- ]T' AND foo REGEXP '^R|[- ]R' AND foo REGEXP '^S|[- ]S'`**

Comment: Can you check my revised question please?